# How to use same image (bitmap) in multiple threads? c#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, bitmap, emgucv

I am trying to create class that will be responsible for finding an image inside a screenshot of a window and clicking at it. Aloso it should show what it has found in winform.

So far I made this:

```
public class CookieClicker : Clicker
{
    private ScreenShotForm workViewer;

    private IntPtr windowHandler;

    private CancellationToken clickerCancelationToken;

    private Bitmap сurrentImage;

    private Bitmap imageWithRectangles;

    private object imageWithRectanglesLocker = new object();

    private string bigCooliePath = "";
    private string goldCooliePath = "";

    public CookieClicker(ScreenShotForm workViewer, IntPtr hWnd, CancellationToken token)
    {
        this.workViewer = workViewer;
        windowHandler = hWnd;
        clickerCancelationToken = token;
        GetTargetsPaths();
    }

    private void GetTargetsPaths()
    {
        bigCooliePath = FileHelper.GetTargetImagesFolderPath() + @"perfectCookie";
        goldCooliePath = FileHelper.GetTargetImagesFolderPath() + @"goldCookie";
    }


    public async Task Run()
    {
        GetCurrentImage();
        ShowImageWithRectangles();

        Task bigCookieClickeTask = Task.Run(() => FindCookie(bigCooliePath));
        Task goldCookieClickeTask = Task.Run(() => FindCookie(goldCooliePath));
        while (!clickerCancelationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            GetCurrentImage();
            await Task.Delay(300);
            ShowImageWithRectangles();
        }
        workViewer.Close();
    }

    private void GetCurrentImage()
    {
        var sc = new ScreenCapture();
        сurrentImage = sc.GetScreenshot(windowHandler);
        imageWithRectangles = сurrentImage.Clone() as Bitmap;
    }

    private void ShowImageWithRectangles()
    {
        Bitmap imageToShow = imageWithRectangles.Clone() as Bitmap;
        workViewer.CopyWindowSize(windowHandler);
        workViewer.SetPictureBoxImage(imageToShow);
    }

    private void FindCookie(string targetsFolder)
    {
        List<string> targetsPaths = ImageHelper.GetImagesFromFolderList(targetsFolder, false);

        List<Image<Bgr, byte>> targets = new List<Image<Bgr, byte>>();

        foreach (string targetsPath in targetsPaths)
        {
            targets.Add(new Image<Bgr, byte>(targetsPath));
        }

        while (!clickerCancelationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Task.Delay(300);
            Bitmap currentImage = this.сurrentImage.Clone() as Bitmap;
            Image<Bgr, byte> source = currentImage.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
            bool isMatchFound = false;
            Rectangle rectangleToClick = new Rectangle();

            Rectangle matchingRectangle = new Rectangle();

            bool isFound = false;

            Parallel.ForEach(targets, (target, state) =>
            {
                isFound = ImageHelper.IsMatching(source, target, out matchingRectangle);
                if (isFound)
                {
                    rectangleToClick = matchingRectangle;
                    isMatchFound = isFound;
                    state.Break();
                }
            });
            if (isMatchFound)
            {
                ClickOnCookie(rectangleToClick);
                DrawRectangleOnImage(rectangleToClick);
            }
        }
    }

    private void DrawRectangleOnImage(Rectangle recToDraw)
    {

        Image<Bgr, byte> source = imageWithRectangles.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
        source.Draw(recToDraw, new Bgr(Color.Red), 3);
        imageWithRectangles = source.ToBitmap();
    }

    private void ClickOnCookie(Rectangle recToClick)
    {
        Rectangle handlerRect = WindowHelper.GetWindowBorderRectangle(windowHandler);

        recToClick.Offset(handlerRect.X, handlerRect.Y);

        LesftMouseClickInRectangle(recToClick);
    }
}
```

[github page for conext](https://github.com/Killancheg/CookieClikerBot)

And it works! But not for long. I always get expetion when miltiple theads try to access Bitmap сurrentImage or Bitmap imageWithRectangles. I tried to use locks or go around the problem with clone, but it did not help.

Obviously I did something very wrong here and I should refactor my code, but I dont know where to start. Maybe there are some general rules for avoiding this kind of poblems?

Will appreciate any hepl you can provide.

Comment: Consider re-ogranizing the code into pipeline to avoid race conditions and ensuring that only one actor/ stage accesses an image at a time.  check out [System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow)

Comment: Might be simpler to reduce the image to raw byte array of the 32-bit colour data, and do your multi-threaded search on that; I doubt you can get threading issues reading a simple byte array.